# Returning a Object in a Hashset in Java

Tags: java, hashcode, hashset

Hi I have a HashSet like the following in a class called Memory:

```
Set<Idea> ideas = new HashSet<Idea>();
```

The generic type "Idea" is another class I wrote that has hashcode() and equals() overriden.
I want to be able to get(and not remove) an Idea object in the HashSet ideas, then change it by adding something to it possibly changing it's hashcode() return value. I heard that this is would not work but no one explained why. I was wondering if someone could tell me how I can do this most efficiently.

Comment: HashSet<K> = HashMap<K,K> you can see this from jdk sources

Comment: I don't understand, will using a HashMap solve my problem. And if so, how? thanks!

Comment: @farmer1992 He wants a Set not a Map

Comment: why would you want to "change" it

Comment: @Hitman47 A better `Idea`?

Comment: @OscarRyz I think he can have the hashcode calculated by Idea's field and when it gets to be retrieved, the field value is changed as well..so it would appear to be a different hashcode...though I don't know whether it's a good idea

Comment: You mean, why change the hashCode? I agree, there is no need. I thought you were asking why changing the idea object.

Comment: A set cannot use "get" to obtain an existing value.  It can only be used to determine if an element exists in the set or not.  A HashMap is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform a lookup, you should be using a Map.  If you want to change the key (or an element of a Set) you have to remove it first and add it again.  For this reason your key should only have immutable fields.

Answer (score 2):

HashSet internally uses HasMap with value same as the key.For putting an object to Hashset, jvm fill first calculate the hashcode of the object and based on that hashcode, corresponding bucket is selected and object is put.So if you are changing the hashcode after putting the object into hashset,you wont be able to get its location correctly.So if you really want to remove the element, better remove the object from hashset change its value and then put it back again

Answer (score 1):

It wont work because the hashcode is the key to find the object, if you modify the object in such a way you change it's hashcode you won't be able to find it again.

It is like the entry in a dictionary, if you change it you won't find it again. Does it makes sense?

Comment: So is the best way to find Idea object, remove Idea object, change Idea object, then add Idea object back to HashSet?

Comment: You can still leave it there granted the hashCode doesn't change

Comment: If you want to change the hashCode you have two options, either the one you mention, remove it and add it again, or use another Set implementation that doesn't realies on the hashCode method

Comment: Are there any other implementations that are still efficient?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not a option. Do you know which implementations do not rely on the hashCode method?

Comment: If you are changing the object it make sense to remove it and add another. Try with TreeSet, and measure, if updating with TreeMap is faster than remove/add with HashSet use that.

Comment: `TreeSet`, but then that depends on the _comparisons_ not changing with the modifications.  Realistically, the most practical option will be removing, modifying, and re-adding...and in practice, that's about the most algorithmically efficient implementation that will exist.